# decrease amount one by one from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I don't see what I am doing wrong. I have in the current account `1000` and from this amount I want to pay commission one by one. The last commission must remain the amount that is not enough  to pay `(20 + 1 + 1000) - 1000 = 2`.

```
declare @CommissionTable table(AccountId INT, Amount DECIMAL(18,2))

INSERT INTO @CommissionTable  VALUES(17584981,20)
INSERT INTO @CommissionTable  VALUES(17584982,1)
INSERT INTO @CommissionTable  VALUES(17584983,1000)

DECLARE @CurrentAmount DECIMAL(18,2)
SET @CurrentAmount   = 1000

declare @ComissToPay decimal(18,2)

;WITH [comis] AS (SELECT Amount FROM @CommissionTable)
UPDATE [comis] set @ComissToPay = CASE                                          

WHEN @CurrentAmount < CM.Amount THEN @CurrentAmount 

WHEN  @CurrentAmount > CM.Amount  THEN CM.Amount
END,

Amount = CM.Amount - isnull(@ComissToPay,0),
@CurrentAmount   =  @CurrentAmount  - isnull(@ComissToPay,0)
from [comis] CM                             

SELECT * FROM @CommissionTable
```

Comment: (20 + 1 + 1000) - 1000 = 2 how do you get 2 ?

Comment: Did you get 21 by chance?

Comment: I'm trying to help you here but I'm not sure what the end result you're looking for would look like. Could you post what you intent to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a recursive CTE the way you're trying to. You'll have better luck with a cursor in this case, I think:

```
DECLARE @CommissionTable TABLE(AccountId INT, Amount DECIMAL(18,2))

INSERT INTO @CommissionTable  VALUES(17584981,20)
INSERT INTO @CommissionTable  VALUES(17584982,1)
INSERT INTO @CommissionTable  VALUES(17584983,1000)

DECLARE @CurrentAmount DECIMAL(18,2)
SET @CurrentAmount   = 1000

DECLARE @thisID INT, @thisAmount DECIMAL(18,2), @ComissToPay DECIMAL(18,2)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT *
FROM @CommissionTable
ORDER BY Amount ASC

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @thisID, @thisAmount

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 AND @CurrentAmount > 0
BEGIN   
    IF @thisAmount > @CurrentAmount
        @ComissToPay = @CurrentAmount
    ELSE 
        @ComissToPay = @thisAmount

    UPDATE @CommissionTable SET Amount = Amount - @ComissToPay WHERE AccountID = @thisID
    SET @CurrentAmount = @CurrentAmount - @ComissToPay

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @thisID, @thisAmount
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor

SELECT * FROM @CommissionTable  
PRINT 'Amount left over: ' + CAST(@CurrentAmount AS VARCHAR(50))
```

This code is untested, because I am away from my desk at the moment, so it may contain some minor syntax errors, but hopefully it is enough to put you on the right track.

Also note the ORDER BY clause I added; I sorted your commissions from smallest to largest so you can get the little ones paid off before you start trying to pay down the big ones.